# Selenium IDE - Pop Ups - How to Automate

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, selenium-ide, popupwindow

I am automating a browser application using Selenium IDE (not webdriver). I am clicking on a web button `create new user` (as an example) and a pop up modal appears, the background is greyed and the new window sits front and centre.

Despite my best efforts, i cant figure out how to get S-IDE to focus on the popup and not the greyed out background.

I have read that i should get the window name but looking at the HTML this is not obvious.

Can anyone help with specifically which selenese action i should use and how i can get ide to focus on the window so that i can continue scripting.

The first line of what i see when i hover over the whole popup using firepath

```html
<div class="osx-modal-data" style="display: block;">
  <div class="osx-modal-data" style="display: block" name="addDeviceForm" id="addDeviceForm">
    <form id="addDeviceForm" class="bbq ui-formwizard ng-pristine ng-valid" name="addDeviceForm">
```

Comment: Check for iframes. Otherwise you just need better xpaths. The pop up is just more HTML from what I can tell, not a new tab/window.

Comment: This feels like it's a dhtml type pop up. So isn't an actual new window.